# Package pydelicious and feedparser

Tags: python, installation, feedparser

I am trying to learn python for online social network from a book. while working for delicious data, its written that

> Data from delicious is made available through an API that returns data in XML
>   format. To make things even easier for you, there is a Python API that you can download

I have downloaded pydelicious and installed it using python setup.py install command on command prompt but when i import in on python command prompt it gives error  Feedparser not available, no RSS parsing.

Then I tried to install feedparser and i found the link https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/tree/develop

but i cannot understand if i m doing correct or not because after downloading it gives error that "no module named setuptoools"

Please help. thanks